# How to smooth a contour using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to find the contours of human hands for gesture recognition.After some pre processing and thresholding, I am extracting the contour. The contours I am getting are as below,

[image: Hand Contour]

I want to smooth out the contour. I tried using scipy.ndimage.zoom but it seems to be changing the dimensions of the input numpy array. How can I smooth out the contour keeping the shape of the input array the same?

Comment: looks good to me but you might want to try `convexityDefects`